# SSH Permission denied (publickey) on my Oracle cloud instance

Tags: oracle, ssh, key-pair

I had to switch to a new PC with linux-subsystem installed.
This means I lost access to the key-pair I generated when I created my free Oracle cloud instance.

Now with the new PC, I'm trying to create a new console connection and generating a new key-pair, but I'm always getting "Permission denied (publickey)."

I have the public IP address and user. I'm able to create the console connection and upload my own .pub key, but I'm not able to troubleshoot this issue.

I was able to copy my original key-pair from my old PC, but that doesn't work either.

I'm locked out of my Oracle cloud instance.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Talk to My Oracle Support.

Answer (score 0):

Hello (I don't have enought reputation to ask you details so I put it here),if I understand right your story, you used the old key to connect.

But can you or not connect to your instance in any way ?

> **I'm able to create the console** connection and upload my own .pub key, but I'm not able to troubleshoot this issue.

> **I'm locked out** of my Oracle cloud instance.

In either way, if you think there is your public key in your instance, you can try forcing the use a the corresponding private key when connecting using `ssh user@ip -i /path/to/private/key` (probably a file in `~/.ssh/`).

If you don't have any private key corresponding to a public one that is present in your instance, you're basically locked out (and you can throw away the instance if there isn't any recovery option on the instance dashboard).

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.
I can create a console connection when using the Web GUI. This allows to generate a console connection with a key-pair. You can then download the private key and use that to connect to the console. However, this doesn't work for me and this is not an ideal solution.

My old PC used the key-pair when I generated the instance. I was hoping to simply copy and paste these keys to my new PC and remote to my cloud instance, but that also isn't working.

Comment: @Noobuntu ok, that's good, you have a way to somehow connect to the instance. If you posses a valid private key, mabe you just need to add the key to you ssh agent like so [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent). Have you tried like i said using the `-i` flag like `ssh user@ip -i /path/to/private/key`. If it works let me edit my answer and you could validate it as a solution

Comment: I'm getting `Error loading key "/home/gil/.ssh/id_rsa": invalid format` when I try to add to the ssh agent.
This is the private key I saved as id_rsa.txt on my windows machine.
I ran `ssh-keygen` to generate keys. I then used nano to overwrite the content of the keys with the contents of the original keys I used when I generated the instance.

Comment: it could be the file extentsion/type, can't you juste use the generated file directly load it instead of coping content ? maybe it was like `.pem` or `.ppk` or something else, try using the original file name (here is a details of what i'm talking about https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file )

Comment: It's not .pem or .ppk. I generated them using ssh-keygen in CLI.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for posting, I had the same problem, in my case somehow it was caused by using DSA public key, maybe it is not supported?  it says:

`debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /Users//.ssh/id_dsa - not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes`

When I tried re-creating the instance with RSA public key it all worked OK then.

To troubleshoot just run a sss -vvv for extra verbose output and see what it tells you (like this snippet above).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to create a new console connection and generating a new key-pair, but I'm always getting "Permission denied (publickey)."

The console and ssh is completely different ways of accessing a session on your VM. You seem to be conflating the two.

Assuming that you were able to login via the console, and deploy your public key in the right place (i.e. replace ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, although the base filename *MAY* be slightly different) then the cause of the "Permission denied (publickey)." error is you have the wrong permissions on the file. Check the filename and `chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

And think about backing up important data like ssh keys.